# Button rounded corners only .TopRight and .BottomRight with constrains

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

Helo guys i found [How to create rounded UIButton with top-left & bottom-left corner radius only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32937349/how-to-create-rounded-uibutton-with-top-left-bottom-left-corner-radius-only) and its working. But problem is when button have some constrains it suddenly stop workin. Can anyone help me with that i tried change everything and still no results.

[image]

As you can see on picture its working for first orange Button in top of a picture but for TWITTER button its not working. Any help please ?

```
extension UIButton{
func roundCorners(corners:UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
    let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
    let mask = CAShapeLayer()
    mask.path = path.CGPath
    self.layer.mask = mask
  }
}
```

and this is usage ( `testBtn` is that orange working button)

```
testBtn.roundCorners([.TopRight, .BottomRight], radius: 20)
    facebookBtn.roundCorners([.TopLeft, .BottomLeft], radius: 20)
    twitterBtn.roundCorners([.TopRight, .BottomRight], radius: 20)
```

Comment: Move testBtn.roundCorners([.TopRight, .BottomRight], radius: 20)
    facebookBtn.roundCorners([.TopLeft, .BottomLeft], radius: 20)
    twitterBtn.roundCorners([.TopRight, .BottomRight], radius: 20) to viewDidLayoutSubviews?

Comment: its working thank you very much.

Comment: whatever, for swift 3.0 see my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40222533/2594699