# Round left border of a UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uibezierpath

To round the bottom left corner of a `UIButton`, I took [code from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32937511/7327018) and modified the line: `borderLayer.strokeColor = GenerateShape.UIColorFromHex(0x989898, alpha: (1.0-0.3)).CGColor` b/c it didn't work.

**However, the left border of the `UIButton` is not rounded. How to fix?**

[image]

**Code**

```
    button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0.5*popUpView.frame.width, height: 0.25*popUpView.frame.height)
    button.layer.borderWidth = 3
    button.roundBtnCorners(roundedCorners, radius: cornerRadius)

extension UIButton{
    // Round specified corners of button
    func roundBtnCorners(_ corners:UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat)
    {
        let borderLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        borderLayer.frame = self.layer.bounds
        borderLayer.strokeColor = UIColor(red: 168/266, green: 20/255, blue: 20/255, alpha: 0.7).cgColor
        borderLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        borderLayer.lineWidth = 1.0
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds,
                                byRoundingCorners: corners,
                                cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        borderLayer.path = path.cgPath
        self.layer.addSublayer(borderLayer);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just change the layer.cornerRadius property? Right now the behavior is normal, your UIButton must be clipped to the bounds of the superView and no cornerRadius is at all applied on the UIButton.

Comment: @SwiftRabbit I only want to round the BOTTOM LEFT corner of the UIButton that's why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it! It was because my `button.layer.borderWidth = 3` was drawing a really thick rectangle, so I couldn't see the border drawn by `roundBtnCorners`

I deleted the line below:

```
button.layer.borderWidth = 3
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Istead of:

```
self.layer.addSublayer(borderLayer)
```

Try:

```
self.layer.mask = borderLayer
```

Comment: Didn't work :/ - it caused the button's text to disappear + the border was very thin & did not show up at the rounded corners

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see how you are creating the parameters for roundBtnCorners but below is the line I changed in your code and it worked. I would check to make sure you are passing the correct parameters.

```
    button.roundBtnCorners(.bottomLeft , radius: 10)
```