# Rounded rect using UIRectCorner in Swift not working

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift2

I am trying to create a rounded rect for the UITableViewCell I have created in a storyboard.  I am using Swift 2 in Xcode 7.  I have two views in the prototype cell, topView and Bottom view.  I want the topView to have its top corners rounds, and the bottomView to have its corners rounded.

in awakeFromNib (may go somewhere else better later):

```
...
self.topView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
self.bottomView.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()

self.setMaskToView(self.topView, corners:UIRectCorner.TopLeft.union(UIRectCorner.TopRight))
self.setMaskToView(self.bottomView, corners: UIRectCorner.BottomLeft.union(UIRectCorner.BottomRight))
...
```

In separate function (based on an answer to another Stack overflow post):

```
func setMaskToView(view : UIView, corners: UIRectCorner) {
    let rounded = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 10, height: 10))
    let mask = CAShapeLayer()

    mask.path = rounded.CGPath
    view.layer.mask = mask
}
```

Note, I also tried [.TopRight, .TopLeft] instead of the union(), based on various other stack overflow posts.  Nothing seems to change anything.  Also cleaned and restarted Xcode in desperation.  This is what I am getting:

[image: Top Cell Shows issue. Only .TopLeft seems to be applied, even though it is called on two separate views]

If anyone has any ideas what might be up, I would appreciate it.

Thanks.

Comment: see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40222533/2594699

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two problems.

1. `awakeFromNib` is too early to do anything based on view bounds, because the views haven't been resized for the device at that point. You should create the mask layers in `awakeFromNib`, but you should set their paths in `layoutSubviews`.
2. In `setMaskToView(_:corners:)`, you need to use `view.bounds`, not `self.bounds`, to create the path.

Comment: Yep, I looked at that dozens of times, and did not see it.  Thanks