# Corner are not round of UILabel and UIbutton ios swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, uibutton, uilabel

I am trying to round three corners of label and button by following this:
[rounded button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40498892/different-cornerradius-for-each-corner-swift-3-ios)

But the result is:

[Image of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiR4z.png)

some corners of labels are rounding and some are not.Similarly its happening with button and width is exceeding and button going out of tableview.

this is the code of extension i am using:

```
extension UIButton{
    func roundedButton(){
        let maskPAth1 = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds,
                                     byRoundingCorners: [.topLeft, .bottomLeft, .bottomRight],
                                     cornerRadii:CGSize(width:8,height:8))
        let maskLayer1 = CAShapeLayer()
        maskLayer1.frame = self.bounds
        maskLayer1.masksToBounds=true
        maskLayer1.path = maskPAth1.cgPath
        self.layer.mask = maskLayer1

    }
}

extension UILabel{
    func roundedLabel(){
        let maskPAth1 = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds,
                                     byRoundingCorners: [.topRight,.bottomRight,.bottomLeft],
                                     cornerRadii:CGSize(width:10,height:10))
        let maskLayer1 = CAShapeLayer()
        maskLayer1.frame = self.bounds
        maskLayer1.cornerRadius=5
         maskLayer1.masksToBounds=true
        maskLayer1.path = maskPAth1.cgPath
        self.layer.mask = maskLayer1

    }
}
```

I am calling these function in

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {}
```

Comment: Making rounded corner in iOS is really easy. All you need is `view.layer.cornerRadius = aFloat`. There's no need to subclass anything and it works on all subclasses of `UIView`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rounded rect using UIRectCorner in Swift not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33050585/rounded-rect-using-uirectcorner-in-swift-not-working)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens because `bounds` of these labels and buttons are most probably different when you call `rounded...()` methods and when they are presented in a table view.

That's because the `bounds` value that you use to create the `UIBezierPath` is different from one that these views have after they are presented in the cell. Table view layouts a cell and if the `CAShapeLayer` you create exceeds its bounds, it gets "cut off".

You should create a subclasses of `UIButton` and `UILabel` that would update the bezier path of their masks every time they layout.

```
class RoundedLabel: UILabel {

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        let maskPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds,
                                    byRoundingCorners: [.topRight, .bottomRight, .bottomLeft],
                                    cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 10, height: 10))

        let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        maskLayer.frame = bounds
        maskLayer.cornerRadius = 5
        maskLayer.masksToBounds = true
        maskLayer.path = maskPath.cgPath
        layer.mask = maskLayer
    }
}
```

As further optimization you could lazily initialize the mask layer (meaning it would be created when it's accessed for the first time) and only change it's frame and path in the `layoutSubviews` method.

```
class RoundedLabel: UILabel {

    private lazy var maskLayer: CAShapeLayer = {
        let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        maskLayer.cornerRadius = 5
        maskLayer.masksToBounds = true
        self.layer.mask = maskLayer

        return maskLayer
    }()

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        let maskPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds,
                                    byRoundingCorners: [.topRight, .bottomRight, .bottomLeft],
                                    cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 10, height: 10))

        maskLayer.path = maskPath.cgPath
        maskLayer.frame = bounds
    }
}
```