# Different CornerRadius to Border for each corner

Tags: swift, uiview, uibezierpath

I try to give corner to view's corners with different size. Firstly, I give corner to all corners about min radius and then I try to change 2 left corner with bigger size.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcdHk.png)

```
func roundCorners(_ corners:UIRectCorner,_ cormerMask:CACornerMask, radius: CGFloat) {
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *){
        self.clipsToBounds = false
        self.layer.cornerRadius = radius
        self.layer.maskedCorners = cormerMask
    }else{
        let rectShape = CAShapeLayer()
        rectShape.bounds = self.frame
        rectShape.position = self.center
        rectShape.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds,    byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius)).cgPath
        self.layer.mask = rectShape
    }
}
```

//

```
viewMoreView.roundCorners(.bottomLeft, [.layerMinXMinYCorner , .layerMinXMaxYCorner], radius: 13)
viewMoreView.layer.borderWidth = 1
viewMoreView.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red:0.81, green:0.83, blue:0.83, alpha:1).cgColor
viewMoreView.clipsToBounds = true
```

This code change left sides but in the right side all changes (radius) is removed.

**With this below link, borderRadius doesnt look properly like this pic!!!**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRNFj.png)

[Different cornerRadius for each corner Swift 3 - iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40498892/different-cornerradius-for-each-corner-swift-3-ios)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is shortcut about this issue

```
    let demoView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: vieww.bounds.width, height: vieww.bounds.height))
    demoView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
    demoView.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0

    let maskPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: demoView.bounds,
                                byRoundingCorners: [.topLeft, .bottomLeft],
                                cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 64.0, height: 0.0))

    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    maskLayer.path = maskPath.cgPath
    demoView.layer.mask = maskLayer

    vieww.addSubview(demoView)

    let demoViewInner = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 2, y: 2, width: demoView.bounds.width-4, height: demoView.bounds.height-4))
    demoViewInner.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    demoViewInner.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0

    let maskPathInner = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: demoViewInner.bounds,
                                byRoundingCorners: [.topLeft, .bottomLeft],
                                cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 60.0, height: 0.0))

    let maskLayerInner = CAShapeLayer()
    maskLayerInner.path = maskPathInner.cgPath
    demoViewInner.layer.mask = maskLayerInner

    demoView.addSubview(demoViewInner)
```

however adding and inner view looks like a solution also. After reshaping of layer, adding border may not be right way.

[image]

Comment: This solution is not compatible with my question.

Answer (score 0):

may be adding sublayer to the view is a clear solution that you can accept

```
let borderLayer = CAShapeLayer()
borderLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
borderLayer.path  = maskPath.cgPath
borderLayer.lineWidth   = 3
borderLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor;
borderLayer.fillColor   = UIColor.clear.cgColor;

viewMoreView.layer.addSublayer(borderLayer)
```

Because adding layer border to the current view does not work as such as you would like. You should use sub layers.