# How to give a rectangular view different corner radiuses without using Bezier Path

Tags: ios, swift

I have to give a corner radius to the rectangular view with one side being more rounded than the other three sides.

Corner masking won't work in iOS 9 & 10, so is there any other way besides using corner masking and Bezier Path that we can use for all the iOS versions?

Update: I wanted to know if there is any way to achieve the same without using UIBezierPath. Any fallback similar to shapelayer for before iOS 11.

Comment: Why can’t you use UIBezierPath?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Different cornerRadius for each corner Swift 3 - iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40498892/different-cornerradius-for-each-corner-swift-3-ios)

Comment: **UIBezierPath** work in every ios version.