# UIView rounded border without bottom or top side

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have UIView which I need to draw a border only partial part view, this is how my design look alike, how do i make it ?

[expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g93wL.png)

Comment: You can see the answer here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10316902/rounded-corners-only-on-top-of-a-uiview

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var droppedView: UIView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        droppedView.clipsToBounds = true
        droppedView.layer.cornerRadius = 24   // 얼만큼 둥글게 할 것인지

        droppedView.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner,
                                           .layerMaxXMinYCorner]
        droppedView.backgroundColor = .systemGray6
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@IBOutlet weak var shadowVw: UIView!

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        shadowVw.layer.cornerRadius = 24
        shadowVw.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner,.layerMaxXMinYCorner]
        shadowVw.backgroundColor = .systemGray6
        shadowVw.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        shadowVw.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7
        shadowVw.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: -5.0)
        shadowVw.layer.shadowRadius = 5
}
```